# Jquery show div on checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i want to display a div when a checkbox is checked. The thing is i have multiple selects and i want to display the form until none is selected. My code is not working exactly as it should because when i deselect a checkbox my div dissapears and it should dissapear only if none is selected.

Here is my js

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#formular").show();
    } else {
        $("#formular").hide();
    }
});
```

also jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/bYuak/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $checks = $('.checkbox').click(function () {
    $("#formular").toggle($checks.filter(':checked').length>0);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P22uj/)

Comment: or even `$("#formular").toggle($checks.is(':checked'));` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P22uj/2/

Comment: why would you assign it to a variable?

Comment: @JamieHutber it is always faster to cache the value of  jquery looks up because it will save dom tree lookup

Comment: opps, i didn't see you were using $checks later :)

Comment: Thnx all for the responses but Arun had the simplest one

Comment: @ArunPJohny I dont quite understand how the assign to checks works. Is the .click method returning a value?

Comment: @Husman almost all jQuery methods(except the getter type methods like `.attr('class')`, `.width()`) etc follows the method chaining principle where the method returns the object on which it was invoked on, so `$('.checkbox').click(....)` returns the same value as `$('.checkbox')`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is called any time a click event is generated for any of your checkboxes, this happens because of this line of code:

```
$('.checkbox').click()
```

In side the event handler, you say :

```
if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#formular").show();
}
```

Which shows the div, and the else statement hides the div, if that element is unchecked. Therefore your code is working as expected. Your implementation however is very different to what you want it to do.

You need to check the state of all the checkboxes, using a loop and then show/hide the #formular div, if they are ALL unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```
function checkCount() {
    // Store count of how many selected
    var boxCount = 0,
        el = $("#formular");

    // Go through each checkbox
    $(".checkbox").each(function (index) {
        //Increase count if checked
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            boxCount++;
        }
    });

    if (boxCount > 0) {
        el.show();
    }
    else {
        el.hide();
    }
}

$('.checkbox').on('change', function () {
    checkCount();
});
```

Comment: I would rather keep the `el.hide()` and `el.show()` which are more explicit.

Comment: I just edited to use `.show()` and `.hide()`, in my project I have a css class for `hide` which I use to hide something by default then I just remove/add that class. My answer does not now need extra css for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple just target all checkboxes when you check.

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
    if(  $('.checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $("#formular").show();
    } else {
        $("#formular").hide();
    }
});
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bYuak/2/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
    if($(".checkbox:checked").length){
        $("#formular").show();
    }
    else{
        $("#formular").hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYuak/3/)

or

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() { 
    $("#formular").toggle($(".checkbox:checked").length>0);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYuak/4/)